# Find function v(x,y) such that f is holomorphic

Tags: analysis

I'm getting stuck on this problem.
Given $u:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ where $u(x,y)$ satisfies
$$\frac{d^2u}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2u}{dy^2} = 0,$$
find a corresponding function $v(x,y): \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f:\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ given by $$f(x+iy)=u(x,y) + iv(x,y)$$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}$.

My approach was to use the Cauchy–Riemann equations to try something and then integrate it maybe but it feels like its not going to get me anywhere.

Comment: Using the Cauchy–Riemann equations is good (one of the standard ways). Why does it feel like it's not getting you anywhere? [How far have you got? You're probably just missing a small observation to finish.]

Comment: I only managed to get to a point where i show that the second derivative of 'v' / dx dy is the same as the second derivative of 'v' /dy dx. Not sure what way i should be looking at from here on.

Comment: What is the condition for a vector field $(a,b)$ on $\mathbb{R}^2$ to be a gradient field? (That is, under which condition(s) does there exist a function $g \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ with $a = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ and $b = \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}$?)

Comment: g has to be continuous and differentiable with respect to x and y in every point of the domain. That would mean that the function 'u' in my case has to be continuous and so has to be 'v'. Not sure where to go from here though.If i may,is it even right what i got as my answer ? That the second derivative of 'v' is the same no matter with which variable we derive  first ? Just want to be sure I'm on the right track at least.

Comment: Yes, $\frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial x \partial y} = \frac{\partial^2 v}{\partial y\partial x}$ is correct. And that (properly translated to the gradient problem) is just the condition that ensures that the vector field $\bigl(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigr)$ is a gradient field, i.e. there is a $v$ with $\frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = -\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}$ and $\frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$.

Comment: So, the answer should be just double integral of second derivation of v / dx dy = v ?

Comment: You have to be careful with that, integrating twice gives you the result only up to a linear function, and you must choose the integration constants correctly to obtain a holomorphic $f$. The answer is the integral of the vector field $\bigl(-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\bigr)$. That is defined up to a constant, but of course adding constants to holomorphic functions gives holomorphic functions.

Comment: Thank you very much, just to make sure, $(-\int\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} dx,\int \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}dy)$, it is this right ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret this. Have you learned about line integrals of vector fields (or of differential forms)?

Comment: No we have not yet, seems like the learning path in my country is a bit different than in others.

Comment: Hm, usually some calculus/real analysis is considered a prerequisite for complex analysis. I don't see how to exhibit such a $v$ without line integrals if we're going the Cauchy-Riemann way. Unless you were given a specific $u$, then one can get a specific $v$ directly without explicitly using line integrals. What techniques have you at your disposal?

Comment: Actually, we have learned about line integrals of vector fields, was just when quarantine started so i had to learn that myself (+ language barrier) and clearly i have holes in the topic. We have complex and real analysis at the same time..But for line integrals i need some curve, what will that be in this case ? No additional info was given to us except the one I stated at the start of the topic.

Comment: The point of the integrability condition is that the choice of the curve doesn't matter (since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simply connected). You can take for example the straight line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(x,y)$, or you can use two line segments parallel to the coordinate axes, or anything else to define $v$.

Comment: Makes sense.So if i parametrize the curve as (t,ty/x), 0<t<x, then v will be line integral of vector fields with  F= $ (-\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}, \frac{\partial u}{\partial x})$ so that would make it v = $\int\frac{\partial v }{\partial x}(t,t\frac yx)*1+\frac{\partial v}{\partial y}(t,t\frac yx)* \frac yx dt$ ?

Comment: Yes, but you can't really use the partial derivatives of $v$ before $v$ is defined. So in the integral defining $v$ use the partial derivatives of $x$. And of course your parametrisation only works for $x \neq 0$ (and $x < 0$ also poses a minor problem). Using $(tx, ty)$ for $t \in [0,1]$ avoids these problems.

Comment: Oh right ! using v when its not defined..silly me..hmm but what do i do after this ? is that what the answer should be just the formula in the integral ?